# PHP cannot import class file

Tags: php, class, oop, import

I have these two php files in the same directory:

**index.php**

```
<?php

    echo "before";

    require('Parser.php');

    echo "after";
?>
```

**Parser.php**

```
<?php

    /**
    * Class Parser
    */
    class Parser
    {

        private $url;

        function __construct($url)
        {
            $this->url = $url;
        }



        public function getUrl(){
            return $this->url;
        }

        public functionsetUrl($url){
            $this->url = $url;
        }

    }

?>
```

I need to import the Parser file because i have to use this class in my index file but i can't.

There is a problem importing this class because if i try to access index.php i can see only the first print: `before`.

I don't know where is the problem but is very strange, my files are so simple.

My php version is 5.6 and i'm using MAMP as web server.

Can someone help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Turn on errors. You probably have a `Fatal Error`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Parser` class:

```
 public functionsetUrl($url){
```

should be

```
 public function setUrl($url){
```

Comment: This is why you use an IDE that detects these kinds of problems as you type.